# Is there documentation somewhere for python-apt in python3?

Tags: python, version-control

I'm trying to `import apt` in python3 so I can use its `VersionCompare()` method.  I keep getting `'module not found'` types of errors.  I'm using a mac.  I tried `brew install python-apt` to no avail.  Is there a version of `apt` in python3 or is there another way to compare versions that's simple?

I need to compare versions that are alpha-numeric, not pure integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parse_version` from `pkg_resources` which is part of `setuptools` which I presume you have installed:

```
>>> from pkg_resources import parse_version
>>> parse_version('2.0a') > parse_version('1.0-a0-dev')
True
>>> parse_version('2.0a') > parse_version('2.0-b-dev')
False
```